# R ggplot2 package load

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, corrupt, reshape2

I'm very new with R (version 3.0.3) and I was working on a little app with `shiny` and `ggplot`. Everything was working fine and then it seems that I'm no more able to load the packages correctly.

Here's my code and the error messages :

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
# Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : lazy-load database 'P' is corrupt
# In addition: Warning message:
# In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’**

library(reshape2)
# Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : lazy-load database 'P' is corrupt
# In addition: Warning message:
# In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘reshape2’** 

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
       headerPanel( h3(textOutput("athleteTxt"))),
       sidebarPanel(selectInput("athlete", "Changer d'athlete :", paste(dataNom$Nom, dataNom$Prenom))),
       mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
       tabPanel('Progression individuelle',
               plotOutput("graphInd")),
      tabPanel('Comparaison par poste',
               plotOutput("graphPosition"),
               tableOutput("tabPosition")),
      tabPanel('Comparaison avec pro',
               selectInput("positionStd", "Choisir un standard pour comparer :",
                           dataStandardsP$Position),
               tableOutput("tabStandards")),
    ))
 ))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What platform is your system (Windows, Linux, etc)?  Does this happen with other packages?  Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling those packages?

Comment: I'm using windows 7. As you can see it happens too  with reshapes2 but not with all packages. And yes I uninstall and reinstall both packages and have still the same error.

Comment: Reference this post. https://github.com/wch/movies/issues/3 . If you have any `install_github` issues, make sure to restart your `R` session in addition to reinstalling the packages.